# PHP - sleep two scripts

Tags: php, sleep

I have one question for you. 
I'm coding in PHP, and I have one program that uses two PHP files, one main file and second file where are functions and etc, that I'm calling in the main file. They are very big scripts with a lot of lines of code.

I want to sleep my program at a certain time from 2 pm to 5 pm EST, but I have a problem how I can write code to sleep program in that period?

I was thinking about to get EST and then put if the condition

```
 (if servertime === EST){
sleep(108000);
}
```

But my big problem is that I have a lot of functions and classes, how to make this globally, to put this in every function, so whenever come 2pmEST, program should go to sleep wherever the function was at that moment?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question lacks information to get any help from [so] users. Please take the [tour], and read through the [help], learn  [ask] a good question? to maximize your chance to get answer to your questions. If you run into a specific problem and if you're stuck, send a description of the problem, including a [mcve] Example and people will be very glad to help you.

Comment: have you tried CRON JOB?

Comment: @SayedMohdAli i didnt, i will google it

Comment: @doks when we need to run the certain script at a certain time, day,  week, and so on we use Cron jobs

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in a tick-function.
http://php.net/manual/de/function.register-tick-function.php

Be carefully - this will be excuted after each tick - if you dont want it in middle of a prozess, you need check it.

Also look here.
http://php.net/manual/de/control-structures.declare.php